# Removing Class Using Jquery According to Parameter Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following button link:

```
<a href="e5f6ad6ce374177eef023bf5d0c018b6" data-id="573" onclick="reEnableBtn(573)">×</a>
```

And the following js:

```
function reEnableBtn(prodId) {

   alert(prodId);
};
```

Until now all good, on click of the link I get an alert with the content: 573 as expected.

Next thing I want to do is with the following html:

```
<a href="/new-page/?add-to-cart=573" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart added" data-product_id="573">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart finished disabled-button"></i>
</a>
```

Within the JS I want to add a removeClass function which removes the classes 'finished' and 'disabled-button' from the `<i>` where the data-product_id of the parent `<a>` matches the value of prodId within the JS function (because I have other links with same structure but different data-product_id).

How do I do this?

Comment: What code have you written for the second part of your question so far? It seems completely unrelated to the first

Comment: You can use jquery function .removeClass("classname") to remove any class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1) use attribute equal selector to target anchor element with same data product id

2) find element i in above anchor element

3) use removeClass to remove multiple classes from it

```
function reEnableBtn(prodId) {
   $('[data-product_id=' + prodId + '] i').removeClass("finished disabled-button");
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working :) Can you please tell how can i add just a small delay to remove this class?

Comment: what is the expected behavior after delaying removeClass?

Comment: after 2 seconds will remove the disabled-button class.

Comment: You can use setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

```
function reEnableBtn(prodId) {
 $("a[data-product_id='"+prodId+"']").find("i").removeClass("finished disabled-button");
};
```

Use this simple script.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
jQuery(function($){

    var s = $("body").find('[data-product_id=573]');

    s.on("click", function(e){
        var i = $(this).find('i');
        if (i.hasClass('finished'))
            i.removeClass('finished');
        if (i.hasClass('disabled-button'))
            i.removeClass('disabled-button');
        alert("The classes was removed.");
        return false; // this is for disabling anchor tag href
    });
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nnmh63Ln/20/)

If you have any other question feel free to ask in comments.